# Child window can not get keyboard after resize parent window

Tags: c++, winapi

I have used `SetParent(childwindow, parentWindow)` to set another window to be a screen in my app. But after my app resizes, this child window can not get any keyboard events.

Comment: Are `childwindow` and `parentWindow` owned by different threads? If so, there's [a lot to know](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683).

Comment: did you see "When you change the parent of a window, you should synchronize the UISTATE of both windows."

Comment: Thankyou, I am trying to read https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171122-00/?p=97445

Comment: That article is only relevant if both windows are owned by the same thread. If they aren't you have to solve a **much harder** problem first (see comment above).

Comment: My problem is not only thread, it is 2 different process.

Comment: Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa#remarks). It is possible that the ChildWindow has lost focus, try using ‘SetForegroundWindow’ or ‘SetActiveWindow’.

Comment: I have tried with ‘SetForegroundWindow’ and ‘SetActiveWindow’, It has not work.

Comment: Did you use `CreateWindow` to create these two windows?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT, I only control 1 of them, 1 is an other app.

Comment: As IInspectable said, this problem is hard to solve if not in same thread.

Comment: I understand how hard of this problem. At first, this problem was reslove by using message WM_LBUTTONDOWN, which would setParent again if it is not OK. But there would be a problem when resize parent window. Futher more, my parent window have some function need overlap child window, but it can not work.